# How to change pointer from base to derived class inside a function

Tags: c++, void-pointers, factory-method

I would like to create some kind of factory function, but instead of returning a pointer to a certain class object, I would like to pass a pointer to the base class to a function as an argument. What makes it even more cumbersome, the function accepts the void pointer.

Here is the code I have tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base {
    public:
    std::string isA()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    std::string isA()
    {
        return "Derived";
    }
};


void func(void* obj)
{
    Derived* derived_ptr = (Derived*)obj;
    std::cout << "Address of derived_ptr " << derived_ptr << "\n";
    std::cout << "From func " << derived_ptr->isA() << "\n";

}

int main()
{
  Base* instance;
  func(instance);
  std::cout << "Address of instance " << instance << "\n";
  std::cout << "From main " << instance->isA() << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Address of derived_ptr 0x4009b0                                                                                                               
From func Derived                                                                                                                             
Address of instance 0x4009b0                                                                                                                  
From main Base
```

From the output it is obvious that the addresses are the same but in each case it is different object (Base and Derived.
Is there a way to get it working in this form?

Comment: In your main function you pass an uninitialized pointer to func().

Comment: You never created your instance. Accessing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behaviour. Moreover you should have declared your method as `virtual` in the base class. Never use `void*` but `Base*` instead. Since a `Derived` ***is*** a `Base`, you can pass a `Derived*`.

Comment: Moreover you are trying to cast a `Base` to a `Derived` object. `Derived` is a `Base`, but `Base` is not necessarily a `Derived`. If you properly used a `dynamic_cast` instead of a C-style cast, you would have received a `nullptr` indicating you that the cast is illegal.

Comment: @Fareanor `dynamic_cast` will not work here without polymorhpism.

Comment: @Waqar Since I mentioned to make the function `virtual` (and that adding a `virtual` destructor is recommended), the class would become polymorphic and thus `dynamic_cast` works ;)

Comment: Yes, however I am failing to understand the question in this post. @vargss, what output do you want? *Is there a way to get it working in this form?* -> this doesn't explain much.

Comment: Not to mention that OP does want polymorphism (hence the `void*` trickery). I did not answer for the same reason as @Waqar, I don't understand what is the ***actual*** question.

Comment: @Fareanor, what makes most of the headaches is that I am unable to change some parts of the system, so the only thing I can pass to a func is a void pointer. I can change the main, I can change the contents of func, but not the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want run time polymorphism via `virtual` functions, you can use `std::variant` instead. This enables you to use unrelated objects without a common base class, it did not need to enable RTTI which means it will fit also for small embedded systems and it still type safe as `std::variant` keeps the information which object is currently stored inside the variant variable.

You also can store such variants in containers as you like. If you use a `std::variant` with a pointer type, the potential waste by using this kind of union is only the additional pointer instance.

But yes, it has another indirection by using the pointer, but in your example you also have a `void*` and "some mind" of check and conversion like a cast.

```
class Base {
    public:
        std::string isA()
        {
            return "Base";
        }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        std::string isA()
        {
            return "Derived";
        }
};

class Another
{
    public:
        std::string isA() { return "Another"; }
};

using VAR_T = std::variant< std::unique_ptr<Base>, std::unique_ptr<Derived>, std::unique_ptr<Another> >;

VAR_T Factory( int what )
{
    switch ( what )
    {   
        case 0: return VAR_T{std::make_unique<Base>()}; 
        case 1: return VAR_T{std::make_unique<Derived>()}; 
        case 2: return VAR_T{std::make_unique<Another>()}; 
    }   

    return {}; 
}

/* Never do such thing in real world code!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */

void func(void* obj)
{
    VAR_T* var = reinterpret_cast< VAR_T* >( obj );
    std::string s = std::visit( []( auto& ptr ){ return ptr->isA(); }, *var);
    std::cout << "From func " << s << "\n";
}



int main()
{
    std::vector< VAR_T > vars;

    for ( int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {   
        vars.push_back( Factory( i )); 
    }   

    for ( auto& var: vars )
    {   
        std::visit( []( auto& ptr ){ std::cout << ptr->isA() << std::endl; }, var );
    }   

    // and now via void*, but never use this in production code. DANGEROUS, NOT TYPE SAFE, 
    for ( auto& var: vars )
    {   
        func( &var );
    }  

}
```

EDIT: Added code with using `void*`, BUT THIS SHOULD REALLY NEVER BE PART OF ANY PRODUCTION SYSTEM! `void*` is always a nightmare!

Answer (score -1):

TLDR: use a static_cast.

```
void func(void* obj)
{
    auto derived_ptr = static_cast<Derived*>(obj);
}
```

If you want dynamic polymorphism this is how your code should look like. But the result of function call to isA will be the same since you created a Derived object. You can use dynamic_cast with a check  to call a method which exists only in derived class.

Update: I added a void* implementation as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Base {
    public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual std::string isA()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    virtual std::string isA() override
    {
        return "Derived";
    }
    void derivedMethod() {
        std::cout << "I am a derived only method\n";
    }
};

void func2(Base* obj)
{
    if (auto derived_ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(obj)) {
        derived_ptr->derivedMethod();
        std::cout << "Address of derived_ptr " << derived_ptr << '\n';
        std::cout << "From func " << derived_ptr->isA() << '\n';
    }
}

void func(void* obj)
{
    auto derived_ptr = static_cast<Derived*>(obj); 
    derived_ptr->derivedMethod();
    std::cout << "Address of derived_ptr " << derived_ptr << '\n';
    std::cout << "From func " << derived_ptr->isA() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    //Base* instance = new Derived();
    std::unique_ptr<Base> instance = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    func(instance.get());
    std::cout << "Address of instance " << instance << '\n';
    std::cout << "From main " << instance->isA() << '\n';
    //delete instance;
}
```